Deployment: NEXT JS APP W Amplify, Missing API Key Even though specified in Environment Variables section
Its my first time deploying with AWS Amplify and I have an API route to send emails for a front end application. The route works fine on localhost and on vercel but when I add the environment variables, deploy the project, and test the API on Amplify it gives status 500.The Build logs show the error as "Missing API_KEY pass it to the constructor", so it should be right where I instantiate the object to send the emails using process.env.local to get the key. Does anyone know why this error is happening, is it something knee deep inside the DOCS I'm missing or common understanding I dont grasp?
the location of my route is "app/api/send or
environment variables added in AWS Amplify
I tried deployment on other platforms and it works. I checked other posts and they were referencing the Build script for the App, however I used similar scripts and it still resulted in the same scenario.
I made the API route in the folder /src/app/api/send/route.js, and called the route as /api/send. I also tried making it a main route and leaving it in just the API folder (/api). I noticed it cant be the environment variable because if I make the object with the API key inside it, it still gives the same errors in the images (on both console, and cloudwatch). I cant crack this nut. For now Ill use vercel, and in the mean time read the docs.
Update with images and new things tried:
image of the API route code
image of the response code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Environment variables need to be passed to your application in your amplify.yml. You can find it under "build settings" in the amplify application. It should look something like this.
build:
  commands:
    - echo "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
    - npm run build

Here is the documentation which talks about this.
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/deploy-and-host/fullstack-branching/secrets-and-vars/
